# How to open certain path in the Samsung Android My Files Programmatically

Tags: android

I'm using the following code to allow the user to access My Files from a Samsung android device.  I'm trying to open certain path in the My Files when the user press the button.  Right now it will open the default path.  Can you tell me if it is possible to pass the path through when open My Files from Android?  Below is the code that I use. Can you give me the code that will open My Files into certain Path?  Thank you in advance for your help.

```
public void AccessingFiles(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("*/*");
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

    // special intent for Samsung file manager
    Intent sIntent = new Intent("com.sec.android.app.myfiles.PICK_DATA");
     // if you want any file type, you can skip next line 
    sIntent.putExtra("CONTENT_TYPE", "*/*"); 
    sIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);

    Intent chooserIntent;
    if (getPackageManager().resolveActivity(sIntent, 0) != null){
        // it is device with samsung file manager
        chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(sIntent, "Open file");
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Intent[] { intent});
    }
    else {
        chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open file");
    }

    try {
        startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, CHOOSE_FILE_REQUESTCODE);
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No suitable File Manager was found.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for the solution to the same question this is how I open My Files pointed at a certain path:

```
File folder = new File(""); // construct the path
Intent fmIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
fmIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.sec.android.app.myfiles", "com.sec.android.app.myfiles.MainActivity"));
fmIntent.setData(Uri.parse(folder.toString()));
```

To be noted that `fmIntent.setData(Uri.fromFile(folder))` did not work for me.

The solution is tested with My Files 1.19.0 and this is how I came to it:

1. I created a custom Launcher;
2. My Files can create home screen shortcuts to a specific path;
3. When the install shortcut intent was sent to my launcher I dumped its contents so that I can use them to create my fmIntent from the above code snippet.